# Whats going on in this bit of JS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm watching an Angular JS tutorial that keeps using variations of this code snippet without explaining it.

```
(function(param, undefined){
  //Normal function definition in here
  ...
}(bar.foo = bar.foo || {}));
```

So I get most if this. I recognize the following a self-executing function used to encapsulate bits of javascript to avoid scope pollution.

```
(function(param, undefined){
  //Normal function definition in here
  ...
});
```

But I don't understand the syntax of having parentheses after a function definition.

*Edit*

I understand what is going on inside the parentheses.
What I don't understand is the syntax of having parentheses after a function definition: `function(...){...}(...);`

Comment: @Xufox, see my edit. I wasn't clear enough on what part was confusing me.

Comment: In that case it’s a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281. I can’t vote to close a second time, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a self-executing function that expects parameters.  `bar.foo` is the parameter that is sent to it (will be `param` in use of the function).
If `bar.foo` does not have a value prior to the execution of the function, it is set to `{}`, otherwise, it is set to itself, and then it is passed in.

```js
(function(param1, param2, param3) {
  var ele = document.getElementById("result");

  ele.innerHTML += "param1: " + param1;
  ele.innerHTML += "<br />";

  ele.innerHTML += "param2: " + param2;
  ele.innerHTML += "<br />";

  ele.innerHTML += "param3: " + param3;
  ele.innerHTML += "<br />";

  param3 = param3 || "bananas";
  ele.innerHTML += "param3 after change: " + param3;

})("apples", "oranges");
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is being triggered with (bar.foo = bar.foo || {}) as the argument. If bar.foo exists, then the function will take bar.foo as the argument. If it is undefined (which is falsey), then it will take in {} as the argument. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Placing parentheses after the function declaration initiates a call to it immediately.  It's the same as doing this:

```
var fn = function () { ... };
fn();
```

Because the return value of a function declaration is the function object, and when you apply parentheses to a function object, you call it.  And, as always, the stuff inside those parentheses are the parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If bar.foo is defined, use that -- but if it isnt, use this empty object (`{}`)

*Edit - to fit new clarification*

Its placement means that before executing the function, it will handle the bar.foo assignment; like setting a default.

Comment: Oh, I actually mean the syntax of `function(...){...}(...);`. I should clarify that.